# How to create the navigation menu with sidebar as on mailchimp.com

Tags: css, user-interface, navigation, sidebar

how can I create navigation with a sidebar like on https://mailchimp.com/?
the sidebar appears when you hover a navigation link, for example, "products", but you still can see other links from the navigation, click on them, hover, etc. Not sure how to implement this because in my case when I hover a link, a sidebar appears and I can't see the navigation

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/512lk.png)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #menu {
        width: 100%;
        height: 70px;
        border: 1px black solid;
      }

      #submenu {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        border: 1px black solid;
        width: 500px;
        background-color: gray;
        z-index: 600;
        display: none;
      }

      .open {
        z-index: auto;
        display: block !important;
      }

      .link {
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .linkOpen {
        z-index: 620;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="menu">
      <a class="link" id="link" href="/" onmouseover="addStyle()" onmouseleave="removeStyle()">link1</a>
      <div id="submenu">
        <ul>
          <li>123</li>
          <li>456</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <a class="link" href="/">link2</a>
      <a class="link" href="/">link3</a>
    </div>
    <script>
      function addStyle() {
        var element = document.getElementById("submenu");
        element.classList.add("open");
        var link = document.getElementById("link");
        link.classList.add("linkOpen");
      }

      function removeStyle() {
        var element = document.getElementById("submenu");
        element.classList.remove("open");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do could be achived by using `z-index` with a proper element nesting.

Here is a basic example (without animations and some smart element proportion / placement): https://codepen.io/etumyan/pen/eYeXKxg